# Windows 7 nVidia drivers either don't install, or don't have audio

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, hdmi

I am running Windows 7 64 Bit, and currently have no audio. I do not have an audio device named "nVidia High Definition HDMI Output" in device manager, but when I installed drivers for what felt like the fourth time, it was something like "nVidia Virtual Audio Output" or something, but now the drivers aren't even working at all. I have a GeForce GTX 1650 GPU, if that helps. I have tried clean installing the drivers multiple times, with the drivers either not working at all, or only the graphics working (no audio.)

Comment: This may occur because Windows 7 will not update any more. Supporting systems and drivers for your card may not be there. Windows 7 is too old to use any more.

Comment: nvidia audio drivers are intended for audio via hdmi. are you using hdmi for audio?

Comment: I'm using HDMI for audio.

Comment: Have you tried a clean install of the drivers?

Comment: Is this Window 7 64-bits? Which is your NVIDIA driver? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Yes, it is 64-bit, the filename of the driver installer is: 472.12-desktop-win7-64bit-international-whql.exe

Comment: No matter what installer file I use, there isn't a checkbox for "HD audio driver", but only for "physX", "GeForce Experience", and "Graphics Driver". I can't find anything close online relating to this.

Comment: Try another OS. If you can't upgrade to Win 10 (only 1 year left) or 11, try a Linux distro.

Answer (score 0):

Your Nvidia GeForce 1650 requires a much newer driver version than the version you tried to install which is the latest to run in the unsupported, obsolete Windows 7.

The newest product the 472.x branch supports is Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, released some years before yours.

Therefore:

**What you want to do is an impossible situation.** And, in any case, *Windows 7 is too old to use*, unsupported, unpatched a **very dangerous to use online**. You may use it, with compatible hardware, for retro-computing projects as long as you don't connect it to the internet.

As commented, *if you can't upgrade to Windows 10 (only 1 year [of support] left) or [Windows] 11, try a Linux distro*. E.g. the beginner-friendly Ubuntu where you can select the option to automatically install 3rd party drivers, codecs, etc. that includes the latest Nvidia drivers, currently the **535**.x branch.